# Create REST API with post params

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have below JSON Data for rest API
`{"region_id":"475","city":"city","item":[{"qty":"1","weight":"","price":"10.0000","sku":"test"}]}`
and i wann to create api class

I do like this

```
/**
 * @api
 * @param string $city
 * @param string $region_id
 * @param array $item
 * @return [].
 */
    public function estimate($city,$region_id,$item);
```

But return Class array does not exist also I use string [] and I get the same error. How I can pass an array as parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass return type `@return array`

Update your code with this solution :

```
/**
 * @api
 * @param string $city
 * @param string $region_id
 * @param array $item
 * @return array
 */
    public function estimate($city,$region_id,$item);
```

**Valid scalar types** include: `mixed` (or anyType), `bool` (or boolean), `str` (or string), `integer` (or int), `float`, and `double`

Any parameters or return values of type array can be denoted by following any of the previous types by an empty set of square brackets []

```
@return array|int|string|bool|float Scalar or array of scalars
```

**Reference**

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

Comment: you're welcome :)